# Checking days from now

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to respect the Ruby principle of keeping my code dry; however, in my conditional, I have different constants set to different days. But that's the only thing different. They're pretty much the same code minus the evaluation of days `from_now`.

```
if term_type == TERM_MONTH
  subscription.suspended_at && subscription.suspended_at < MONTHLY_WARNING_1.from_now && suspended_email_1_sent_at.nil? && subscription.suspended_at >= Date.today && is_system == true && paid_at.nil?
else 
  subscription.suspended_at && subscription.suspended_at < ANNUAL_WARNING_1.from_now && suspended_email_1_sent_at.nil? && subscription.suspended_at >= Date.today && is_system == true && paid_at.nil?
end
```

I tried using the ternary operator; however, it didn't produce the results I was expecting as it was only setting the days based on `term_type` yet not sending the mail based on it.

```
days = term_type == TERM_MONTH ? MONTHLY_WARNING_1 : ANNUAL_WARNING_1
subscription.suspended_at && subscription.suspended_at < days.from_now && suspended_email_1_sent_at.nil? && subscription.suspended_at >= Date.today && is_system == true && paid_at.nil?
```

Should I stick with the `if` block?

Comment: I've edited your post to include the original code you had posted on SO - please see [a guide to CR for SO users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788) on meta; we prefer to see your real code, in its "native habitat", unlike SO which prefers distilled examples. If you have more context code, feel free to [edit] and add it in - usually the more context, the better the reviews.

Answer (score 2):

Some notes:

- More declarative: `x.nil?` -> `!x`
- More declarative, idiomatic and compact: `is_system == true` -> `is_system`.

A first obvious refactor is DRYing the common conditions using a local variable (a temptative name, you'll know what's more fitting):

```
unpaid_subscription_suspended = subscription.suspended_at && 
    !suspended_email_1_sent_at && subscription.suspended_at >= Date.today && 
    is_system && !paid_at

if term_type == TERM_MONTH
  unpaid_subscription_suspended && subscription.suspended_at < MONTHLY_WARNING_1.from_now
else 
  unpaid_subscription_suspended && subscription.suspended_at < ANNUAL_WARNING_1.from_now
end
```

A second refactor is to refactor the conditional and move all the expressions to the `if`/`elsif` predicates:

```
case
when !(subscription.suspended_at && !suspended_email_1_sent_at &&
       subscription.suspended_at >= Date.today && is_system && !paid_at)
  false
when term_type == TERM_MONTH && subscription.suspended_at < MONTHLY_WARNING_1.from_now
  true
when term_type == TERM_YEAR && subscription.suspended_at < ANNUAL_WARNING_1.from_now
  true
else
  false
end
```

As an additional advice, you should group those conditions into methods. For example the first chain of conditions may be abstracted as `Subscription#unpaid_subscription_suspended?`.

Comment: `nil?` is asking if it’s nil, `!` tells you its falsey, so it could be `false` or `nil` and pass... right? Everything else is truthy (yes, even 0 is truthy). I want to check if it's nil. if you have an expression like `if !in_trouble` that’s kinda nice, compared to `if in_touble.nil?`, but overall, I like the `.nil?`.

Comment: Yes, it does not tell nil from false (from a logic standpoint it's not relevant, you want to know if they are set or not). That's the idiomatic way in Ruby: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not stick with the `if` block. Definitely not.

First, let me recommend shorter line lengths. I'm not a stickler for 80 characters per line, but 200 is a bit much. ;)

Second, I do not understand your comment about the ternary operator. The following code should be functionally equivalent to your first code sample:

```
duration = term_type==TERM_MONTH ? MONTHLY_WARNING_1 : ANNUAL_WARNING_1

is_system &&
subscription.suspended_at &&
subscription.suspended_at < duration.from_now &&
subscription.suspended_at >= Date.today &&
!suspended_email_1_sent_at && !paid_at
```

Depending on what `subscription` is, I might suggest adding a method that returns that portion of your test. For example:

```
class Subscription
  def email_ready( duration )
    if t=suspended_at
      t < duration.from_now && t >= Date.today
    end
  end
end

# ...

is_system && !paid_at && subscription.email_ready( term_type==TERM_MONTH ? MONTHLY_WARNING_1 : ANNUAL_WARNING_1 )
```

Finally: the `_1` smells like something bad. Is there an `_2`? An `_3`? If so, these should likely be in an array or other ordered structure, not named constants for each.